# HTML elements moving

Tags: html, css

I'm encountering an issue where elements on my webpage are not maintaining their positions within their designated sections when I zoom out. Despite my attempts to inspect and adjust the elements' properties, I'm unable to identify the root cause of this behavior.

Here are the relevant details:

I've set up my CSS with fixed positioning and specific sizing for various elements on the page.
The elements include a header, sections, and specific components like images and divs.
I've tried adjusting units (e.g., percentages, viewport units) and experimented with different positioning properties (e.g., relative, absolute).
I've also ensured that parent containers are appropriately configured.
However, the issue persists, and I'm at a loss for what might be causing this unexpected behavior.

Additional Information:

I've inspected the elements using browser developer tools but haven't been able to pinpoint the exact CSS properties responsible for the movement.
Could someone kindly review my CSS and HTML code snippets to help me identify what might be causing this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Account Safety Systems</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Your Account Issues.</h1>
    </header>

    <section>
        <div class="aboutitc">
            <div class="aboutith">
                <h1>Actions taken to your account:</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="actions" id="actions1">
            </div>
            <div class="actions" id="actions2">
            
            </div>
            <div class="actions" id="actions3">
            
            </div>
            <div class="actions" id="actions4"> 
            </div>
            <div class="actions" id="actions5">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="input-container">
        <input type="text" id="inputField" placeholder="To test this please input a warning" style="width: 300px; height: 100px;">
        <button id="addButton">Add Warning</button>
    </div>
    <section>
        <div class="line">
            <div class="linepoints hidden" id="linepoints1">
                <img src="tick.png" alt="tick" style="height: 70px;">
            </div>
            <div class="linepoints1 hidden" id="linepoints2">
                <img src="6898883.png" alt="Warning" style="height: 60px;">
            </div>
            <div class="linepoints2 hidden" id="linepoints3">
                <img src="203c.png" alt="warrrnnn" style="height: 66px; top: 2px; position: relative;">
            </div>
            <div class="linepoints3 hidden" id="linepoints4">
                <img src="24-241608_nuclear-symbol-radiation-symbol-black-and-white.png" alt="nuke" style="height: 52px; top: 10px; position: relative;">
            </div>
            <div class="linepoints4 hidden" id="linepoints5">
                <img src="x-mark-transparent-24.png" alt="x" style="height: 60px; top: 5px; position: relative;">
            </div>
            <div class="line1 hidden" id="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2 hidden" id="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3 hidden" id="line3"></div>
            <div class="line4 hidden" id="line4"></div>
            <div class="line5 hidden" id="line5"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="pfp">
        <div class="pfpwar hidden" id="linepointz">
    </div>
</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: monospace;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    width:100%;
}

header{
    padding: 20px 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10000000000;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 3px gray solid;
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.hidden{
    background-color: gray !important;
}

.line{
    background-color: gray;
    height: 20px;
    width: 600px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: 39%;
    top: -305px;
    z-index: -2;
}
.pfp{
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: url(download.png);
    background-position: center;
    left: 34%;
    top: -375px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
.pfpwar1{
    height: 136px;
    width: 136px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 33.85%;
    top: -508px;
    position: relative;
}
.pfpwar2{
    height: 136px;
    width: 136px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 33.85%;
    top: -508px;
    position: relative;
}
.pfpwar3{
    height: 136px;
    width: 136px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 33.85%;
    top: -508px;
    position: relative;
}
.pfpwar4{
    height: 136px;
    width: 136px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 145, 0);
    z-index: 2;
    left: 33.85%;
    top: -508px;
    position: relative;
}
.pfpwar5{
    height: 136px;
    width: 136px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 33.85%;
    top: -508px;
    position: relative;
}
.linepoints{
    background-color: green;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    left: 80px;
    top: -25px;
    align-items: center;
}
.linepoints1{
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
    top: -93px;
    
}
.linepoints2{
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    left: 320px;
    top: -163px;
}
.linepoints3{
    background-color: rgb(255, 145, 0);
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    left: 440px;
    top: -233px;
}
.linepoints4{
    background-color: red;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    left: 560px;
    top: -303px;
}
.linepoints img,
.linepoints1 img,
.linepoints2 img,
.linepoints3 img,
.linepoints4 img {
    display: block;
    margin:  auto;
}
.linepoints:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
.linepoints1:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
.linepoints2:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
.linepoints3:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
.linepoints4:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
.line1{
    background-color: green;
    height: 20px;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: -350px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.line2{
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    height: 20px;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    top: -370px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.line3{
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 20px;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: 210px;
    top: -390px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.line4{
    background-color: rgb(255, 145, 0);
    height: 20px;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: 330px;
    top: -410px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.line5{
    background-color: red;
    height: 20px;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: 460px;
    top: -430px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.aboutitc{
    height: 300px;
    width: 800px;
    background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
    position: relative;
    left: 32.3%;
    top: 250px;
    z-index: 4;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}
.aboutith{
    height: 80px;
    width: 800px;
    background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
    font-size: x-large;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: rgb(255, 255, 255) 3px solid;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: -100px;
}
.actions{
    border-bottom: black 4px solid;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-size: x-large;
    text-align: center;
}
.input-container{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    top: 200px;
    left: 2.5%;
}
/* width */
.aboutitc::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    margin-right: 2px;
  }
  
  /* Track */
.aboutitc::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 0.5px;
  }
  
  /* Handle */
.aboutitc::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: rgb(29, 29, 29);
    border-end-start-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  /* Handle on hover */
.aboutitc::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #555;
  }
```

I have attempted to change the widths with different measurements this didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution I had

```css
position: relative;
```

not

```css
position: absolute;
```